# Detected task failure: docker service create --name db --network backend --mount type=volume,source=db-data,target=/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, overlay, docker-swarm, docker-machine

I'm running Docker with Bash on windows 10.

Inside my VM node1, when I run this command

```
docker service create --name db --network backend --mount type=volume,source=db-data,target=/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:9.4
```

I get:

```
overall progress: 0 out of 1 tasks
1/1: ready
verify: Detected task failure
♥Operation continuing in background.
Use `docker service ps tm3hgzidbr2smnpc7f2tz1w67` to check progress.
```

Why did the task fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

I was missing an argument that is mandatory for postgres authentication: `-e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust`.

From [Docker HUB documentation on Postgres](https://hub.docker.com/r/ubuntu/postgres):

> ```
> -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
> ```
>
> Set the auth-method for host connections for all databases, all users,
> and all addresses. The following will be added to the pg_hba.conf if
> this option is passed: host all all all $POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD.

so I removed my `db` service

```
docker service rm db
```

and replaced it with

```
docker service create --network backend --mount type=volume,source=db-data,target=/var/lib/postgresql/data --name db -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust postgres:9.4
```